# How can I redirect Magento Store URL's to WooCommerce Store URL's?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, woocommerce

I am trying to make a 301 redirect from a Magento Store URL to a Woocommerce Store URL. Here is what I used in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/customer/account/ /my-account/
```

That should redirect the Magento Account page to the WooCommerce My Account page.
 However, when you try to go to */catalog/index.php/customer/account/* on my new site it redirects you to */shop/customer/account/* (which does not exist on my site).
Again, I have another redirect in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/greeting-cards.html /product-category/greeting-cards/
```

And again, */catalog/index.php/greeting-cards.html* is redirecting to */shop/greeting-cards.html* instead of the URL I specified in my .htaccess file. All the URL's with the base of */catalog/* are redirecting only their base to */shop/*.
 My .htaccess file is working because I have another redirect in there:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us.php /about-us/
```

And that redirect works.
There must be some rule from WordPress or WooCommerce that rewrites */catalog/* to */shop/*. So how do I redirect a Magento Store URL to a WooCommerce store URL?

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks!

*I am running:*
WordPress **3.8.3**
WooCommerce **2.1.5**

**Site URL:** http://www.thepottersheart.com/

**Full .htaccess file:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /about_us.php /about-us/
Redirect 301 /catalog/ /shop/
Redirect 301 /contact_us.php /contact-us/
Redirect 301 /calendar.php /calendar/
Redirect 301 /what_people_say.php /testimonials/
Redirect 301 /where_we_go.php /where-we-go/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php /shop/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/customer/account/ /my-account/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/checkout/cart/ /cart/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/checkout/onepage/ /checkout/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/customer/account/login/ /my-account/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/grace-dvd-and-pottery.html /product-category/grace-dvd/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/greeting-cards.html /product-category/greeting-cards/
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php/worship-flags-praise-flags.html /product-category/worship-flags-praise-flags/
```